# How can I pass an argument to the __init__() of an rpyc.SlaveService object?

Tags: python, object, initialization, rpyc

This is my working code:

```
class RPyCService(rpyc.SlaveService):
    def __init__(self, conn):
        super(RPyCService, self).__init__(conn)
...

from rpyc.utils.server import ThreadedServer
my_threaded_server = ThreadedServer(RPyCService, port=RPYC_SERVER_PORT)
my_threaded_server.start()
```

---

However, I would like to pass some arguments to the Services' `__init__()`.
I tried

```
class RPyCService(rpyc.SlaveService):
    def __init__(self, conn, asdf):
        super(RPyCService, self).__init__(conn)
...

from rpyc.utils.server import ThreadedServer
asdf = "asdf"
my_threaded_server = ThreadedServer(RPyCService(asdf), port=RPYC_SERVER_PORT)
my_threaded_server.start()
```

but this gave me

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "rpyc_server.py", line 145,
>   in 
>       my_threaded_server = ThreadedServer(RPyCService(asdf), port=RPYC_SERVER_PORT) TypeError: **init**() takes exactly 3 arguments
>   (2 given)

I am not sure if I have to add the `conn` argument somehow too. I was wondering where it comes from anyway ...

Passing an argument to an exposed service method is not an option in my case. I need to pass the argument when the services' `__init__()` is called.

How can I pass an argument to the `__init__()` of an `rpyc.SlaveService` object?